# Delphi's "Object TreeView" equivalent in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: delphi, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm just getting started in Visual Studio 2010 and I'm coming from Delphi 7.

In Visual Studio 2010, what is the equivalent to Delphi's Object TreeView?

Or to ask it another way, in Visual Studio 2010, during WinForm Gui development, how do you navigate your Gui hierarchically?  If I have, say, a bunch of Panels with some of them inside of others and some Docked to Client, how can I directly select a specific Panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's something similar called `Document outline`, you can get it from

View Menu > Other Windows > Document Outline

[image]